# Is there a way to programmatically check that user choose "Require password after sleep" on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there a library or a tool to check if user choose "Require password after sleep"? Thanks in advance! Example code will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the screensaver preferences.
If you do this you'll see it:

```
defaults read com.apple.screensaver askForPassword
```

You can use the NSUserDefaults APIs to read this programmatically from Cocoa like this:

```
NSDictionary *prefs=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.screensaver"];
BOOL isSet = [[prefs objectForKey:@"askForPassword"] boolValue];
```